# Как передать список в конструктор класса в С#?

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть конструктор класса "Банк". Тут нам надо передать имя, номер паспорта и количество счетов клиента, а так же вклады на каждом счете. Как в конструктор передать список вкладов?

```
public Bank(string name, string passport, int colSchet, )
{ 

}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w5zay9db.aspx попробуй params[]

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bank(string name, string passport, int colSchet, IReadOnlyList<Deposit>  deposits)
{ 
}
```

Так вы сможете передавать в конструктор любую коллекцию, которая реализует этот интерфейс, в том числе массивы (`Deposit[]`) и листы (`List<Deposit>`). Если вам надо, чтобы Bank мог изменять коллекцию, используйте интерфейс `IList<Deposit>`.

Вообще, не понятна логика. Конструктор используется для инициализации объекта. Разве банк зависит от одного конкретного клиента? Мне кажется, вам надо заменить слово Bank на Client.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше сразу `IEnumerable` (если конструктору не нужно обращение по индексу, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой, наверное, способ - это добавить еще один параметр в конструктор и получится что-то вроде такого:

```
public Bank(
   string name, 
   string passport, 
   int colSchet, 
   IEnumerable<Contribution> contributions)
{ 
    // код Вашего конструктора
}
```

Но, если Вы не хотите добавлять новый параметр в конструктор, то можете сделать немного иначе, во время инициализации создать или присвоить коллекцию:

```
var bank = new Bank("name", "passport", 1) 
{ 
    Contributions = new List<Contribution>() // я решил создать
    {
        new Contribution(1), 
        new Contribution(2),
        new Contribution(3)
    }
};
```

И потом в отладке все видно, что все в порядке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только свойство `Contributions` должно быть `public`.
Это чисто формально, для примера, если у Вас есть класс `Contribution`, который в Вашем классе - это список, ну в смысле если так:

```
public class Bank
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public string Passport { get; set; } 
   public int ColSchet { get; set; } 
   public List<Contribution> Contributions { get; set; } 

   public Bank(string name, string passport, int colSchet)
   {
       Name = name;
       Passport = passport;
       ColSchet = colSchet;
   }  
}
```

Ну и где-то есть класс `Contribution` конечно же:

```
public class Contribution
{
     public int Value { get; set; }

     public Contribution() { }

     public Contribution(int value) 
     {
         Value = value;
     }          
}
```